# Horizontal scroll header of Vertical Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a header that is a list itself and the header of a recycler view (I want to be able to scroll it horizontally, and the list vertically)

Here is a pic of what i want to achieve : 
[image]

Can someone please help me on how to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: What are the problems you're facing? Show your code so far.

Comment: I don't know how to do that (how to add the horizontal scroll on the first row)

Comment: It won't be as simple as a single layout. You'll need a RecyclerView with two types of viewHolders. The header (that can scroll horizontally) holders and the other holders.

Comment: Ok and the holder that can scroll can be another recycler but horizontal ?